# HTML CSS image responsive website

Tags: html, css

[image: What it should look like]

[image]

Hey I'm trying to make a responsive website and when I change the size of the screen as the background changes size the image comes off the bottom and changes the verticle location. Help would be appreciated.

```
  <div class="imagess">
  <img style="margin-left: 400px; margin-top: -103px; " src="images/Phone.png"/>
</div>
.imagess {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}
```

Comment: please provide live link, so, I can check , what is actually problem

Comment: Why did I get -4 on this?

Comment: no one understand your question. :D

Comment: Well there were some smart people who answered it. But I should explain it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make use of `css calc()` function to set top positioning of element as below.

```css
.imagess {
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height:800px;
   overflow:hidden;
   background:#111;
}
.imagess > img{
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:300px;
  right:0;
  top:calc(100% - 90%);
}
```

```html
<div class="imagess">
  <img src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

make a class for img tag . this is the css to make img-responsive. And I just confused about your structure.Coz image style margin-left and margin-top confused me. SO this is just an example.

```css
.imagess {
   position: relative; 
   width: 100%; /* for IE 6 */
}

.img-responsive{
width:100%;
height:auto;
display:block;
margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="imagess">
  <img class="img-responsive" src="https://repairexpress.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/repair-express-vernon-samsung-galaxy-note-4.png"/>
</div>
```